# Log4j + JSF - Log file is empty

Tags: java, log4j

I have:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class RIPLoggerObject {
    public final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RIPLoggerObject.class);

// old stuff where i was using java util logger
}
```

log4j.properties:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file,stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender


log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Users\Madjura\\workspace\\yatta1\\test.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I have a working .xhtml page with a button, the button calls a function in a backing bean:

```
public String invite() {
    RIPLoggerObject.logger.fatal("The test works");
// other stuff that shouldnt be important
}
```

Then, in the console in Eclipse I get:

```
2016-05-31 17:53:58 FATAL RIPLoggerObject:85 - The test works
```

But test.log remains empty. No exceptions or anything. The file exists and the path to it is correct too.

Thank you for reading!

EDIT: If I delete the test.log file it does not create a new one, but it also does not throw an exception or complain about the lack of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the log location to:

```
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Users\\Madjura\\Desktop\\log.log
```

Works. If someone can explain WHY that fixes my issue I will accept their answer instead, but for now if someone has a similar issue, setting the log file location to somewhere outside the project folder seems to work!

Comment: May be because inside the workspace, eclipse might be loading it and hence logger not able to write.